# How to remove the last character from a column of data from a CVS file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to do a linear relation using a csv file with 3 columns of data.  Unfortunately I am unable to read the 3rd (last column as int because it has an `';'` in the end of each value. For example `213124121;`, `1231231;` etc.

```
data["the price;"] = df['the price;'].astype('int64')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '399900; '
```

How can I remove the `';'` for the whole column?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple change
`df['the price;']` to  `df['the price;'][:-2]`

it called string slicing in python, you can read more about it in [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

Thanks @[stovfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7414759/stovfl) to spot a mistake in my answer